# SQLite Left Join 2 tables with more than 1 matching registers

Tags: sqlite, join

I need to left join two tables.

table: movies

```
id  title       ext
1   Terminator  mp4
2   Matrix      mkv
3   Predator    mkv
```

table: audio

```
id  language    codec   bitrate
1   English     AAC     320
2   English     AC3     640
2   Spanish     AAC     320
2   German      AAC     320
3   English     DTS     640
4   Japanese    AAC     320
```

When I use the Left Join stament:

```
SELECT title, language, codec
FROM movies M LEFT JOIN audio A
ON (M.id=A.id)
```

I get this result:

```
   title        language    codec
1  Terminator   English     AAC
2  Matrix       English     AC3
2  Matrix       Spanish     AAC
2  Matrix       German      AAC
3  Predator     English     DTS
```

What I want is to have language and codec grouped in one column.
I need this result:

```
   title        language                      codec
1  Terminator   English                       AAC
2  Matrix       English - Spanish - German    AC3 - AAC - AAC
3  Predator     English                       DTS
```

I am pretty newbie in SQLite. I will appreciate any help and enlightenment.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need grouping and [`group_concat()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat). Something like:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title
     , group_concat(a.language, ' - ') AS language
     , group_concat(a.codec, ' - ') AS codec
FROM movies AS m
LEFT JOIN audio AS a ON m.id = a.id
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY m.id;
```

which gives:

```
id     title                 language                        codec
-----  --------------------  ------------------------------  --------------------
1      Terminator            English                         AAC
2      Matrix                English - German - Spanish      AC3 - AAC - AAC
3      Predator              English                         DTS
```